# Update Parameters method gives the same initial and updated values - MLP ANN

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mlp

I have written an MLP ANN code for a binary classification dataset and am getting `0.88` (88%) Accuracy for my training dataset. My Testing dataset gives me `0.37 - 0.55` Accuracy.

I noticed this was due to my parameters not being updated after the UpdateParameters method as shown below:

```
def update_parameters(parameters, grads, lr):

param1 = parameters
L = len(parameters) // 2

for l in range(L):
    parameters["W" + str(l+1)] = parameters["W" + str(l+1)] - lr * grads["dW"+str(l+1)]        
    parameters["b" + str(l+1)] = parameters["b" + str(l+1)] - lr * grads["db"+str(l+1)]
    
print(param1==parameters)

return parameters
```

The above function gave me `True` for all the initial and updated values comparison.

UpdateParameters function is called in the following function:

```
def ann(X, Y, dimensions, lr, lr_decay, batch_size, epochs, loss, activations, gradient_alg):
L = len(dimensions)             # number of layers in the neural networks
m = X.shape[1] 
costs = []                       # to keep track of the cost 

parameters = initialize_parameters(dimensions)
param1 = parameters

if (gradient_alg == "b"):
    batch_size = X.shape[1]

for i in range(epochs):
    minibatches = random_mini_batches(X, Y, batch_size)
    cost_total = 0
    
    for minibatch in minibatches:
        
        (minibatch_X,minibatch_Y) = minibatch
        last_A, caches = forward_prop_layers(minibatch_X, parameters, activations)
        
        cost_total += compute_cost(last_A, minibatch_Y, loss)
        
        gradients = backward_prop_layers(last_A, minibatch_Y, caches, activations)

        parameters = update_parameters(parameters, gradients, lr)
        
    cost_avg = cost_total /m
        
    if i %10 == 0:
        print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" %(i, cost_avg))
    costs.append(cost_avg)
            
plt.plot(costs)
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.title("Learning rate = " + str(lr))
plt.show()

parameters1 = [parameters, param1, dimensions, activations, costs, lr, batch_size]

return parameters1
```

Is my function not being called properly? Where exactly am I going wrong in my implementation?

Comment: Is the loss changing in each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah, here’s why it’s returning True. First you’re assigning `param1` to `parameters`. Then you’re updating `parameters`. But since `param1` is pointing to `parameters`, even after updating `parameters`, `param1` still points to the same memory location of `parameters`. In python everything is treated as an object. Try printing out some `parameters` before and after updating, and then check manually if they are changing or create a copy of `parameters` using deepcopy which copies everything in `parameters` to a separate memory location.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

def update_parameters(parameters, grads, lr):
    param1 = deepcopy(parameters)
    L = len(parameters) // 2
    for l in range(L):
        parameters["W" + str(l+1)] = parameters["W" + str(l+1)] - lr * grads["dW"+str(l+1)]        
        parameters["b" + str(l+1)] = parameters["b" + str(l+1)] - lr * grads["db"+str(l+1)]
    print(param1==parameters)
    return parameters
```

Also try printing out the loss after each iteration, If it is changing, then the `parameters` are getting updated, if not then your `parameters` aren't getting updated properly.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! My parameters were being updated since the loss was changing after each iteration, but I'm failing to understand why testing accuracy does not improve. This is batch gradient descent btw.

Comment: It's clearly overfitting, ie it is memorising the training data, rather than generalizing. Also are you sure that the train and test data are from the same distribution?